# Can not import libgdx project to Intellij IDEA 14

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I want to import libgdx project to Intellij IDEA 14 with gradle 2.4. But I can not do. Because when I try to import,  Intellij gives error that "resolve error, Already created an SDK Loader with different SDK Path".

I set sdk.dir in local.proporties file. Also I did not set ANDROID_HOME in path.

[image]

[image]

How can I proceed?

Comment: when I imported my libgdx project, I did set the ANDROID_HOME. try to set it?

Comment: It is solved. But I dont know how I solved.
I had set Android_home after that I remove it from path. Both of them did not work. However after I restart computer, it is work. I dont understand why it is work.

Comment: Same for me in Android Studio, reboot fixed the issue.

Comment: To solve this error, just you need to restart your system. After that no error is detected in eclipse. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wonder if it was caused by using IntelliJ after using Android Studio on the same machine? I got rid of this problem by deleting ~/.gradle but I think that caused other problems, because the libgdx project wouldn't build the desktop module before running it, then kept hanging with high CPU load when I clicked the build button. I ran the project's gradlew in a terminal to see what would happen, and it downloaded a new zip of gradle and seems to have fixed the problem.